# Java Time insertion in Mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a simple list of strings containing the following data sample. I am able to pass the data from my list to Entity class that has a feild of type `Date` I am also performing a string to date conversion
`SimpleDateFormat sTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")  this.itime = sTime.parse(itime);` 
before inserting it into the database.

**Issue:** The time value being inserted into the table is incorrect!. Where am I going wrong?

Hopefully, I've provided enough information for you to formulate an answer.

**Sample Data**

```
ZZZZ,T0001,00:15:39,15-NOV-2019
ZZZZ,T0002,00:30:39,15-NOV-2019
ZZZZ,T0003,00:45:39,15-NOV-2019
...
...
...
```

Here is a snippet of my code that extracts the time(3rd value) from the list

```
map.entrySet().stream().forEach(v -> { 
                String[] items = v.split(",");
                if (items[0].equals("ZZZZ")) { 
                    slice[0] = items[1];
                    mTime[0] = items[2];
                    mDate[0] = items[3];
                    try {
                        // load data into nmon_interval table
                        IntervalData i = new IntervalData(hostId,slice[0],mDate[0],mTime[0]);
System.out.println("mTime[0] :"+mTime[0]+ ", TSLICE: "+ slice[0] );
                             System.out.println("ITIME: "+i.getItime()+", TSLICE: "+i.getTslice());
                        r.save(i);
```

Here is the IntervalData class...

```
@Entity
public class IntervalData {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "interval_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "interval_generator", sequenceName = "interval_seq")
    private Long id;
    private String tslice;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date idate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date  itime;

    @ManyToOne
    //@JoinColumn(name = "id" , nullable = false)
    private Host host; 

    @Transient
    SimpleDateFormat sTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    @Transient
    SimpleDateFormat sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-yyyy");


    public IntervalData() {
        super();
    }

    public IntervalData(Long hostId, String tslice, String idate, String itime) throws ParseException {
        this.tslice = tslice;
        this.itime = sTime.parse(itime);
        this.idate = sDate.parse(idate);
        this.host = new Host(hostId,"");
    }
```

output from log...

```
mTime[0] :00:15:39, TSLICE: T0001
ITIME: Thu Jan 01 00:15:00 PST 1970, TSLICE: T0001
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from interval_seq for update
Hibernate: update interval_seq set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from interval_seq for update
Hibernate: update interval_seq set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into nmon_interval (host_id, idate, itime, tslice, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select intervalda0_.id as id1_3_, intervalda0_.host_id as host_id5_3_, intervalda0_.idate as idate2_3_, intervalda0_.itime as itime3_3_, intervalda0_.tslice as tslice4_3_ from nmon_interval intervalda0_ left outer join nmon_host host1_ on intervalda0_.host_id=host1_.id where host1_.id=? and intervalda0_.idate=? and intervalda0_.itime=?
mTime[0] :00:30:39, TSLICE: T0002
ITIME: Thu Jan 01 00:30:00 PST 1970, TSLICE: T0002
```

Mysql Database table definition and query result...
[image]

```
select * from nmon_interval order by 4 desc;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your date is wrong as well. it should be `2019-11-15`. Might help you to use `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`

Comment: Great catch!... I didn't even see that... I was so preoccupied with solving the time issue

Answer (score 0):

most likely it's timezone problem.
You need to check your MySQL timezone settings and set them to UTC

Comment: SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone; returns SYSTEM,SYSTEM. based on mysql docs... 'SYSTEM', indicating that the server time zone is the same as the system time zone.

Comment: more info... SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone%'; system_time_zone is set to UTC